# A convergence problem in the space of tempered distributions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let  $K(x):=|x|^{-\alpha}$ be a function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus\{0\}$ with $0<\alpha<n$. Suppose $\phi$ is a $C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function such that

$$\text{(i)}\quad \text{supp}\phi \subset \left\{\frac{1}{2}<|x|<2\right\},$$
$$\text{(ii)}\quad\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \phi(2^{-k}x)=1.$$

Let $$g(\xi):=\mathcal{F}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\phi(2^{-k}x)K \right)(\xi),$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ denotes Fourier transform.

Problem: show that
$$g(\xi)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}\left(\phi(2^{-k}x)K \right)(\xi)$$
with convergence in the space of tempered distributions.

Given a Schwartz function $\psi$, we need to show that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{m}\langle \mathcal{F}\left(\phi(2^{-k} x)|x|^{-\alpha}\right),\psi\rangle \to\langle \mathcal{F}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\phi(2^{-k} x)|x|^{-\alpha}\right),  \psi\rangle.$$
Equivalently, we need to prove that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{m}\langle \phi(2^{-k} x)|x|^{-\alpha},\widehat{\psi}\rangle=\langle \sum_{k=1}^{m}\phi(2^{-k} x)|x|^{-\alpha},\widehat{\psi}\rangle\\
\to
\langle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\phi(2^{-k} x)|x|^{-\alpha},  \widehat{\psi}\rangle.$$

My argument is simple:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\phi(2^{-k} x)\to \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\phi(2^{-k} x)$$
which is a bounded continuous function (Recall that
$\phi$ is smooth and $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(2^{-k} x)=1$). Also, $|\cdot|^{-\alpha} \widehat{\psi} $
is an $L^1$ function. So the passing of the limit is now justified by the dominated convergence theorem.

Did I get the question correctly ? And if so is the solution correct ?

Comment: The details actually don't matter, this follows from the fact that the FT is continuous on $\mathcal S'$.

Comment: Which can be easily proved: If $T_{n}\to T$ in $\mathcal{S}^{\prime}$ then $$\langle \mathcal{F}T_{n},\phi\rangle=\langle T_{n},\mathcal{F}\phi \rangle\to \langle T,\mathcal{F} \phi \rangle=\langle \mathcal{F}T,\phi \rangle$$ for every $\phi \in \mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Thank you, prof. Remling.